# Restart mysql after ending process

Tags: mysql

I ran an sql via the mysql command prompt, but it was taking too long so I decided to stop it. I closed the window, but I could see in Task Manager that mysqld.exe was still using 50% of my CPU. I therefore ended that process via the task manager. But now I don't know how to reconnect to  MySQL. If I try to start a mysql command prompt again, I'm told that it can't connnect. I also tried "net start MySQL" but it says that the service name is invalid. Last time, I ended up restarting my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two options: If you are using MySQL as a service then you must have killed the service. You should go to Start Menu -> Run... and then execute *services.msc*. Look for MySQL service there and start it.

If you are not using MySQL as a service then you'll have to look for the executable and execute it again.

Note: If you got it working after a restart then I bet you're running it is as a service set to start automatically.

Comment: Your bet was right. It was running as a service and this worked perfectly.